# Return a multidimensional associative object from linq2entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Disclaimer: very first c# project

I'm working on an export script which needs to export data from a sql database to csv. I am trying to get linq2entities to do most of the grunt work so that I can avoid unneccesary loops.

I would like to however seperate my linq2sql response into 2 objects (or a sub object refer to below as "calcs") of which the sub contents needs to be able to provide me with a key / value pair as I will need the key name later in my calculations to assign the output to a mapped key from another table.

I have tried a couple of iterations but cannot for the below working. The syntax appears correct but as it is now (below) I cannot even get a count (Any), if I just assign it as a normal list I get a rowcount but I am not able to access the sub object within the 2nd foreach loop.

So is it possible to return a mixed "sub object" from linq2sql and if not, what is my options?

```
  public ActionResult Process()
    {
        // Getting the data:
        using (printmanEntities db = new printmanEntities())
        {

            var result = (
                from u in db.CustomerUsages
                join c in db.Customers on u.CustomerId equals c.Id
                join e in db.Centers on u.CenterId equals e.id
                where u.Status == 1
                group u by c.Code into gr
                select new
                {
                    CustomerId = gr.Key,
                    CenterCode = gr.FirstOrDefault().Center.CenterCode,
                    CustomerCode = gr.FirstOrDefault().Customer.Code,
                    // Is the below possible?
                    calcs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>
                    {
                         new KeyValuePair<string,int>("TPrintBw",gr.Sum(u => u.TPrintBw)) ,
                         new KeyValuePair<string, int>("TPrintCol", gr.Sum(u => u.TPrintCol)),
                         new KeyValuePair<string, int>("TCopyBw", gr.Sum(u => u.TCopyBw)),
                         new KeyValuePair<string, int>("TCopyCol", gr.Sum(u => u.TCopyCol)),
                         new KeyValuePair<string, int>("TScan", gr.Sum(u => u.TScan)),
                         new KeyValuePair<string, int>("TFaxBw", gr.Sum(u => u.TFaxBw))
                    }
                });

            if (result.Any())
            {

                AllCodes = db.Codes.ToList();

                dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
                dt.Columns.Add("CenterCode", typeof(String));
                dt.Columns.Add("BLANK", typeof(String));
                dt.Columns.Add("CustomerCode", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("ServiceCode", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Qty", typeof(Int32));

                foreach (var v in result)
                {
                    // I need to iterate through the items in the subobject here:
                    foreach (var i in v.calcs)
                    {
                        if (i.Value > 0)
                        {
                            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                            dr["Date"] = DateTime.Now;
                            dr["CenterCode"] = v.CenterCode;
                            dr["BLANK"] = "";
                            dr["CustomerCode"] = v.CustomerCode;
                            dr["ServiceCode"] = GetServiceCode(i.Key);
                            dr["Qty"] = i.Value;
                            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        }

                    }
                }

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                                  Select(column => column.ColumnName);
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
                }
                string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyddMM") + ".csv";
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(HttpContext.Server.MapPath(@"/csv/exports/" + filename), sb.ToString());

            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is that LINQ to Entities requires projecting to types with parameterless constructors and property setters, and `KeyValuePair` (as well as `Tuple`) does not meet that criteria and cannot be used.

One way would be to create and project to your own type, similar to `KeyValuePair` but compatible with EF:

```
public class KeyValuePairDto<TKey, TValue>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
calcs = new List<KeyValuePairDto<string, int>>
{
    new KeyValuePairDto<string, int> { Key = "TPrintBw", Value = gr.Sum(u => u.TPrintBw) },
    new KeyValuePairDto<string, int> { Key = "TPrintCol", Value = gr.Sum(u => u.TPrintCol) },
    new KeyValuePairDto<string, int> { Key = "TCopyBw", Value = gr.Sum(u => u.TCopyBw) },
    new KeyValuePairDto<string, int> { Key = "TCopyCol", Value = gr.Sum(u => u.TCopyCol) },
    new KeyValuePairDto<string, int> { Key = "TScan", Value = gr.Sum(u => u.TScan) },
    new KeyValuePairDto<string, int> { Key = "TFaxBw", Value = gr.Sum(u => u.TFaxBw) },
}
```

Another way is to project to list of anonymous type (via array initializer combined with `ToList`), which is supported:

```
calcs = new []
{
    new { Key = "TPrintBw", Value = gr.Sum(u => u.TPrintBw) },
    new { Key = "TPrintCol", Value = gr.Sum(u => u.TPrintCol) },
    new { Key = "TCopyBw", Value = gr.Sum(u => u.TCopyBw) },
    new { Key = "TCopyCol", Value = gr.Sum(u => u.TCopyCol) },
    new { Key = "TScan", Value = gr.Sum(u => u.TScan) },
    new { Key = "TFaxBw", Value = gr.Sum(u => u.TFaxBw) },
}.ToList()
```

Comment: I've updated my code according to yours (http://pastebin.com/ESMrywyQ) but getting an exception on ToList() - An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code  Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Also, in my 2nd foreach loop I am unable to read i.Value or i.Key

Comment: (1) What EF version are you using? The above works in EF6.1.3 (2) `var i in v.calcs` the variable `i` type is the anonymous type having `Key` and `Value` properties, so your code should compile w/o problem.

Comment: Using 6.1.3 - It does appear to be something with the return, I am unable to get any values from the query. I'm beginning to feel 2 queries might be the best option

Comment: Got it working, changed [] to List<dynamic>, thank you

Comment: You are welcome. But `dynamic` adds some overhead, you'd better use the option #1 then.